# SwiftUI VStack Animation looks broken - Animated View will not change position

Tags: animation, swiftui, vstack

Let's take a look at the following Code Snippet:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isViewHidden: Bool = false
    let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Hide", action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isViewHidden.toggle()
                }
            })
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { _ in
                VStack {
                    Text("Foo")
                    if isViewHidden {
                        Text("Bar").animation(nil)
                    }
                }.padding().background(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that the Text("Hide") will animate the position inside the parent VStack.
But it will stick to its last position and fade from there and also animate back to that position. Is there a possibility to give this animation a more natural feel so it will animate inside its parent.

Here is a gif that visualizes the Problem:
[image]

Comment: Actually I cannot image what did you expect... it animates as it asked. SwiftUI containers tight to content, not vice versa... plus default opacity transitions for "Hide"... plus all cells at a moment.

Comment: Can't you see how the view moves out of its container during animation?

Comment: The larger the Y value of the view to be hidden, the more the view moves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Bar` is a new `View` and thus just fades or appears at its final destination, so its position doesn't animate because it previously wasn't on screen.

The trick is to keep `Bar` on screen at all times and just adjust its `opacity`.  `.offset` is used to keep the view from growing due to the word `Bar` that isn't always present.  A blank text view `Text(" ")` is added or removed to cause the view to grow as before.

Here's the workaround that gives a better looking animation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isViewHidden: Bool = false
    let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Hide", action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isViewHidden.toggle()
                }
            })
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { _ in
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        Text("Foo")
                        Text("Bar")
                            .offset(y: 28)
                            .opacity(isViewHidden ? 0 : 1)
                    }
                    if !isViewHidden {
                        Text(" ")
                    }

                }.padding().background(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here it is running in the simulator:

[image: Demo in the siumlator]

---

**Solution 2:  Use `.matchedGeometryEffect`**

Here's a solution that uses `.matchedGeometryEffect` to animate between `Text("Bar").frame(height: 0)` and `Text("Bar")`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State private var isViewHidden: Bool = false
    let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Hide") {
                withAnimation {
                    isViewHidden.toggle()
                }
            }
            ForEach(data, id: \.self) { id in
                VStack {
                    Text("Foo")
                    if isViewHidden {
                        Text("Bar").frame(height: 0)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: id, in: namespace)
                    } else {
                        Text("Bar")
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: id, in: namespace)
                    }
                }
                .padding().background(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an alternate solution with `.matchedGeometryEffect`.  Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for putting even more work into this. 
I accepted this as an answer but to be honest, it still seems hacky for me.